# How to make font-awesome icons thinner

Tags: font-awesome

I've seen some old posts here regarding the subject and i was wondering perhaps there is any new way to control the thickness of Font Awesome icons, 
besides using -webkit-text-stroke.

Comment: What version...?

Comment: @zer00ne doesn't matter really , i'll use whatever  version  it's working ...

Comment: You can use light icons using .fal class instead of .fas. There are no thinner icons in Font Awesome.